# Automatically connect to any wireless network in range

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Is there an application or utility for Windows that will keep scanning for public unprotected wireless networks, and when one is found, automatically connect to it?

Comment: Would this include malicious wireless hotspots designed to accept any connection so that the PC can be scanned for vulnerabilities and compromised?

Comment: Uh... those exist? :(

Comment: If it can be considered, it exists, unfortunately.  Connecting devices together in a network opens risk avenues.  This is why corporates do all they can to control what accesses their networks (both internally and externally) and why individuals should take care in what they expose themselves to when connecting to a network.  This is why your domestic router contains a firewall.

Comment: Sucker-bait WiFi LANs probably [exist](http://www.airtightnetworks.com/home/resources/faqs.html) (see Wi-Phishing). Also in some places it is a criminal offence to use other people's WLANs without permission, even if inadequately protected.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not clarify wether you have seen the network before, or wether you are talking about a completely new network (say at a new airport). If you have seen the network before, you can just check the "Connect automatically" checkbox  when you click on the unsecured network. 
The above works wor WIN-7 64 Bit Home Premium.